Exchanging an operator product with infinite summation
Suppose that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\boldsymbol{v}_{n}$ with $a_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite dimensional vector and $\boldsymbol{O}$ an operator on that vector space. My question is -- under what conditions can one perform the iteration below?
$$\boldsymbol{O}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\boldsymbol{v}_{n}\,=\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(\boldsymbol{O}\boldsymbol{v}_{n})$$
As it seems, unitary transformations allow to satisfy this equality. Are there any other type of transformations?

Your operator $\boldsymbol{O}$ must be linear, the series on both sides of the equality should be convergent, and lastly $\boldsymbol{O} \left(a_n \boldsymbol{v_n}\right) = a_n \left( \boldsymbol{O} \boldsymbol{v_n}\right)$ i.e. $a_n$ is a scalar

@Kraken Since this equality is between two vectors, it not clear to me what do you mean by the sentence 'the series must be convergent'. Maybe you meant that the norm of the resulting vectors must exist.

Yes, that is indeed what I meant, sorry

@Kraken Can one find non-unitary transformations that allow to satisfy the equality sign?

I doubt; will check and get back to you
